# C# system.io Access Denied on XML Document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file

```
    private void ConstructListFromXML(string filePath)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath);
        try
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
            ...
```

The code throws an error when the doc.Load tries to run, saying that access is denied. How can I deal with this access issue? I've been looking to no avail

Comment: Can you please review [MCVE] guideline on posting code and [edit] question to clarify what you mean? Exception on `.Load` call would be expected, but you say that exception happens in `foreach` - if that indeed the case you should be able to inline XML file (smallest possible version still showing the error) to make question self-contained.

Comment: Did you have some other part of your code leave the file open?  Say, an XmlWriter or some other Stream object pointing to this file that was never disposed?  That's a common way to see this problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I apologize, the error does happen on doc.Load

Comment: @SeanSkelly This is the only place that the file gets opened in :/

Answer (score 0):

Access Denied runs also when you input a directory into it.

Comment: How do you know? There is not even trace of this information in the question. It can be plenty of the reasons - directory is one, but it's unlikely to be the case as `filePath` seem to be about a path to a file. You can suggest edit/edit the question to clarify...